# PHP Loop with SQL Query inside has extra OR on the end

Tags: php, sql

I have a loop where i run a query inside:

```
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {
    $sql.="status = '".$ret["name"]."' OR ";
}
```

but when i echo `$sql` outside the loop there is an extra OR on the end of query so its not running properly.

How can i fix this?

Comment: another way would be to create a string of where clause columns inside an array and just `implode` those elements, then you won't get those extra `OR`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RTrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) will help you

```
$sql = '';
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {
   $sql.="status = '".$ret["name"]."' OR ";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ' OR ');
```

Comment: @charlie you should add a leading space after `OR `

Comment: @Ghost In `$sql.="status = '".$ret["name"]."' OR ";` or the second? OP may not know which one ;-) well, it's kind of obvious what you mean though lol (my duh).

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah that might be confusing, just add a leading space on the `rtrim($sql, 'OR ');` since the ending string produced will leave out `OR<space>`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are my solution

```
$sql1='';
foreach($array["results"] as $ret) {
    if($sql1!='')
        $sql1.=' OR ';
    $sql1.="status = '".$ret["name"]."'";
}
$sql.=$sql1
```